# getting google sheets to ignore the first X number of rows instead of writing empty strings to them

Tags: arrays, string, google-sheets

I have the following formula to automatically insert the date in column B if the corresponding cell in row A contains data

However there are already rows that have been filled out manually from before I decided to try automate this and I don't want to lose the data

so I have the following formula (note 5 is used here just for testing purposes. in final application there are more than 100 populated rows I am trying to skip over

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B:B)=1,"Date",IF(ROW(B:B)<5,"",IF(A5:A<>"",TODAY(),""))))
```

however it keeps returning the following error

> Error
> Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B2.

As far as I can tell this is because it is attempting to write an empty string to these cells. Is there a way to have it not do this and simply start from row X?

I tried to wrap the formula in an IfERROR statement but that did not work and as seen above I attempted start referencing only from cell 5 onward but tat didnt work either

=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(ROW(B:B)=1,"Date",IF(ROW(B:B)<5,"",IF(A:A<>"",TODAY(),""))),""))

Comment: The error message clearly indicate that you have data in `B2` cell. Delete data from those cells. Functions can skip any cells to put data.

Comment: the point of the question is that I don't want to delete that data.  I just want it to start the fuction AFTER that data but that data being the causes the formula to stop functioning. EG I have data in cells b2-b4 and I want to formula to start functioning from cell b5 onwards.

Comment: Yes. That is not possible by functions only. You have to use AppScript or put formula after that cell.